# is there another way to turn on "Allow booting from external media" in Mojave?

Tags: boot-camp

[image: message]

when I boot into 'Recovery mode' and select 'Startup security utility' there are no options available.. it asks to 'turn on password protection' which I did, and then when I booted again it asked me to disable it.. neither time (nor since) did it show any other options..

so, how can I "Allow booting from external media"? (I'm trying to 'boot camp'..)

Is there some 'Terminal' voodoo I can use?

EDIT

It's a MacBook 9,1 / Mid 2012.

It has always booted from external in the past - I've been using 'Windows 2 Go' (Win7) from an M2 [in a caddy] for a few years quite happily.

For a project I need to do something with an app that will only run on Windows 10.

First, I tried to set up 'Dual-Boot' (7 & 10) on the M2, but no dice.

Then tried a whole bunch of times (I'm 3 full work-days into this now :O) to put 10 on a partition on my mac system drive (so it would be Mojave / Win 10)

- followed 3 different videos of 'How to blahblah without Boot Camp'.
  Each time it has booted from the flash drive and has let me go through the first steps but then the installation craps out mid-way through:

['can't carry on' message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xf9W.jpg)

Endless issues with having to make, then delete, then remake partitions.. which led to this:

[Windows installation created a partition it couldn't see..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCZIB.jpg)

Right now I'm trying the third type of approach (using a copy of 'Boot Camp Assistant' with a modified plist) and it's giving me the message in the pic in orig post.

When I boot 'Command+R' and select 'Utilities' I'm not shown any of the options that the YouTubers get.. I just get the "enable password" box - which just leads to a loop as described above - and can't go further.

(sorry, I didn't take a pic of this bit yet - I will update here with a pic. if I try again)

So, my question is as above: Is there another way to enable 'Allow booting from external media’? - maybe some terminal commands?

UPDATE

I just tried booting up my 'Windows [7] 2 Go' from my external M2 drive. It works. Flawlessly. So this message makes no sense:
[I'm keenly reminded why I use a Mac.. I basically NEVER have computer problems until Microsoft is involved!! :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiq7S.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198 & get us a screenshot or photo of what you *do* see in the startup utility. Also, knowing precisely what Mac it is might help.

Comment: I've been here (support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198) - it's not a T2 (as far as I know..?). MacBook 9,1 / Mid-2012. Mojave.

Comment: That's… odd. a 2012 doesn't even have a T1 chip, let alone a T2, so there's no Startup Security Utility. What version of the BC setup assistant are you using? iirc it should be 6.1 for Mojave.